# why i am not getting Grid view is not getting top in WindowsFormsHost with panel

Tags: c#, wpf, windowsformshost

On Button click i have to show my grid view content on WindowsFormsHost(Panel),my grid view is accessible but WindowsFormsHost(Panel) is not hidden.

Comment: Is the GridView you're talking about wpf?

Comment: Yes,i will explain waht i did

Comment: 1)Added the panel 2)Added the Button  2) Added the Grid (Visibility is Collapsed) 4)On button click I want to set Grid view( visibility is visible)